# How to pass multiple parameter in URLFOR in Custom Button JavaScript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, url

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("apex/dummy_VFP?id="+ customObject__c.Id)}';
```

> The above one is working perfectly, but when I tried to pass one extra parameter its giving up syntax error, below I tried:

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("apex/dummy_VFP?id="+ customObject__c.Id&buttonType:"conf")}';
```

> Please suggest on above.
>   Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("apex/dummy_VFP?id="+customObject__c.Id+"&buttonType=conf")}';
```

Comment: `{!URLFOR($Page.dummy_VFP, null, [id=customObject__c.Id, buttonType=conf])}` is the formal way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

do you want to open a vf page on click of button.
then here we go. 
button Type:

1. Display type: Detail page button
2. Behaviour: execute js
3. Content source: Onclick js

   `window.open('/apex/section?id={!Account.Id}&name={!Account.Name}')`

and if you want to play with window.open funciton. Here are the properties.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp